# Android - fragment life cycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

As far as I got, **Android fragment** is a part of an **Android Activity.** So is a **fragments** life cycle also same as **activity** or not. I'm very much confused on this matter. Please someone help me. Thank You!!!

Comment: Did you read `Documentation API Guide on Fragments` before ask your question: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do have a look at the [API Document for fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and you will have clear idea about Fragment and its lifecycle

Comment: I have figure 2 of this document printed and taped up at my desk. Super handy for visualizing the fragment life cycle.